# What does the "Move to" option for Pycharm tool windows do?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Let's look at the Navigation tool window - which defaults to the `Left Top` .  I actually clicked on the `gear` icon/settings and selected `Left Bottom` instead:

[image]

Well as we can see the Navigation tool window is still in the upper left.  So then

- what is that `Move to` actually doing?
- how can the Navigation tool window be moved to the bottom left?

**Update**:  I tried this in *Intellij* and it did what I had expected:

[image]

In this case the setting was for `Bottom right` and it is exactly there.  Is this a bug in `Pycharm` only?

Comment: Sorry to nag, but if I understood your correctly, In PyCharm you're moving toolbar to bottom-left, but in IDEA you're moving toolbar to bottom-right, and then compare results. I suggest to be more consistent with the testing.

Comment: Ya  I had tested them the same way initially but then tried another way with Pycharm - and that was the only screenshot I had. Might update again in couple days with consistent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the "Project" toolbar to the bottom-left may appear to do nothing, unless you move another toolbar, (e.g. structure) to top-left. See the attached screenshot.[image]